# Weird ruby error pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm currently using rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.3.0 and I set up everything correctly. Ran rake db:migrate, bundle install, set up heroku right with the right ssh keys, and pushed it to heroku but it's giving me this long list of errors I have no idea why and haven't been able to find anyone else posting this problem. Does anyone have an idea? I have pg in my gemfile under the production group.

```
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/app/models/model.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:315:in `get'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:345:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:345:in `add_mapping'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Caused by:
remote:        Gem::LoadError: can't activate pg (~> 0.15), already activated pg-1.0.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:377:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:316:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/app/models/model.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `constantize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:315:in `get'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:345:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:345:in `add_mapping'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_f31b20b847caecf6a3cf00e2a3b180b2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

Comment: How does your `Gemfile.lock` look like? Does it contain the `pg` gem?

Comment: "weird" is very cryptic and unfindable by someone with similar error. Topic may be "Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded error while pushing to heroku"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to replace:

```
gem 'pg'
```

to:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
```

then run `bundle install` and commit then push.
Rails still have some issues with `pg` latest version.
Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: Why go back to 0.18 when 0.21 works fine? 0.18 version is more than 2 years old. The problem with rails and gem pg is for version 1.0. Use `gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0` instead.